# Select column when IF is true

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I have a scenario like this..

Meta_values table

```
ID |  question_id | m_id | m_value
----------------------------------
1  |  1           |  1   |  Easy 
2  |  1           |  2   |  Physics
3  |  2           |  1   |  Hard 
4  |  2           |  2   |  English
```

Meta_table

```
ID |  Meta
------------
1  |  Difficulty
2  |  Subject
```

I want to write a stored procedure that selects a row when Difficulty=Easy AND Subject = English. Any ideas.?
Here is what i did so far

```
BEGIN

SELECT
    a.q_id,
    a.q_text,
    b.answer , 
    IF(
        c.m_id=1 AND c.m_value = d,
        c.m_value,
        IF(
            c.m_id=2 AND c.m_value=s,
            m_value,
            m_value
        )
    ) as selection
FROM
    question_pool AS a,
    answers_table AS b,
    meta_prop_values AS c
WHERE
    a.q_id = b.q_id
    AND
    a.q_id = c.q_id    
ORDER BY
    Rand() LIMIT n;
```

Here is the output. But it is not exactly what I want

```
 q_id           q_text      answer    selection
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    7   <p>Another difficult question for English</p>   Difficult 3 0
    12  <p>Physics Equations 4&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = {{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p>  Easy 2  Physics
    14  <p>Find values of x from&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = a^2 + b^2 - c\)</span> when a =5 b = 5 c= 10</p> 14  Hard
    12  <p>Physics Equations 4&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = {{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p>  Easy 1  Physics
    6   <p>This is a easy english question</p>  Easy 03 0
    6   <p>This is a easy english question</p>  Easy O2 English
    16  <p>Find values of x from&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = a^2 + b^2 - c\)</span>&nbsp;when a =20&nbsp;b = 20&nbsp;c=-40</p>    457 0
    5   <p>This is another Question with Demo data</p>  Nothing 0
    5   <p>This is another Question with Demo data</p>  Cravitto    English
    15  <p>Find values of x from&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = a^2 + b^2 - c\)</span>&nbsp;when a =10&nbsp;b = 10&nbsp;c=-40</p>    45  Hard
    15  <p>Find values of x from&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = a^2 + b^2 - c\)</span>&nbsp;when a =10&nbsp;b = 10&nbsp;c=-40</p>    45  0
    15  <p>Find values of x from&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = a^2 + b^2 - c\)</span>&nbsp;when a =10&nbsp;b = 10&nbsp;c=-40</p>    43  0
    9   <p>Physics Equations 1&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p>  Easy 4  0
    15  <p>Find values of x from&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = a^2 + b^2 - c\)</span>&nbsp;when a =10&nbsp;b = 10&nbsp;c=-40</p>    54  Mathematics
    9   <p>Physics Equations 1&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p>  Easy 1  Medium
    5   <p>This is another Question with Demo data</p>  Junaid Rasheed  Easy
    2   <p>Testing&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)</span></p>  100 0
    17  <p>Find values of x from&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = a^2 + b^2 - c\)</span>&nbsp;when a =50&nbsp;b = 50&nbsp;c=-40</p>    435 0
    16  <p>Find values of x from&nbsp;<span class="math-tex">\(x = a^2 + b^2 - c\)</span>&nbsp;when a =20&nbsp;b = 20&nbsp;c=-40</p>    457 Hard
    8   <p>A hard &nbsp;question for English</p>    Hard 3  Medium
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Your 2nd-level `IF` doesn't do anything useful as it returns `m_value` in both cases.

Comment: @Dai that is exactly the reason my it shows wrong output. because if i left it empty it shows an sql error

Comment: @Dekel question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're afer is the question ID. this would be one way.

```
SELECT Question_ID
FROM Meta_values V
INNER JOIN Meta_Table T
 on V.m_ID = T.ID
WHERE m_value in ('Easy','English')
GROUP BY Question_ID
HAVING count(*)=2
```

note the m_value and =2 would be passed in dynamically as long as you always know the number of m_values being looked for you set the 2 to that value.

If you need more data, use this as an exists or an inline view join to limit to only the questions matching this resultset.

Comment: this returns the row when any one of the condition "Easy" or "English" is true...but I want to check both.

Comment: This will return 2 rows.   ID's 1 and 4.  in your sample data.  Since Id's 1 and 4 have question #'s 1 and 2 then the count(*) would be 1 which isn't 2 and no records would be returned.  However if we looked for 'Easy' and 'Physics' then rows 1 and 2 would be returned since they both tie to question 1 then the count would be 2 and the question 1 would be returned.

Comment: You are the real savior Sir, Thanks alot :)